# Calculation of stray magnetic field from substation transformers

Tags: transformer, magnetics

Say I want to assess the magnetic field attributed to some substation equipment and the cables in the substation area. Calculating the contribution from the cables and busbars are for my purposes done using the Biot-Savart formula. I do not have access to expensive modeling software (e.g. Narda EFC-400 or SUBCALC) - I have developed my own script for the Biot-Savart calculations in 3d/complex geometries.

However, I'm running out of ideas on how to calculate the stray field of the distribution transformers (in this scenario let's say it's a dry-type distribution transformer 1MVA). I suppose I could use mesurements from similar transformers, made right next to a similar transformer, as a starting point and then just assume that the field magnitude decays as 1/r^3 - but this will not capture any cancellation effects etc between the transformer stray field and the fields from conductors/busbars.

Is there any way to determine the stray field from a transformer without using measurements or FEM software? Old rule-of-thumb formulas would be sufficient.

Comment: Do you want a worst-case number? or will you only accept a 7.5% error? How about 10:1 over ?

Comment: A worst-case number would suffice for now. As long as the uncertainty/inaccuracy can be qualitatively assessed then anything will do really. I am in the process of adding this feature to my program so anything is better than nothing at this point.